# Lens out of focus? - Digicam Panasonic Lumix DMC-FH20

Tags: lens, sensor

Recently, the pictures on my digicam have been coming out like this (img 1) — out of focus, and with a black corner on the right. The black corner would disappear if I tilt the camera to the left (img 2).

I think this may be an issue of the lens decentering, or an issue with the sensor, but I'm not certain. Does anyone have any ideas?

Possible causes: I recently lent the camera to a friend, and they used it till the battery ran out, but forgot to turn the camera off, which may have caused the damage. The camera may also have been bumped around in my bag.

Has anyone had experiences with similar issues, and is this fixable? I've contacted a camera repair shop, and I'm waiting on a reply. In the meantime, I'd really appreciate the community's opinions & input :)) Thanks in advance!

[image: 1: Blurry, black corner]

[image: 2: Blurry, no black corner]

Comment: Is it repairable? Maybe. Is it worth repairing? Almost certainly not, unless you have a particular attachment to that specific piece of hardware. Just find something equivalent on eBay.

Comment: This is 14 years old camera. Exclude the sentiment and think about new one.

Comment: This certainly looks like a fixable mechanical defect but if there are any parts broken it will be expensive to fix it reliably because a lot of parts are unique in these cameras and cannot be obtained because there is no demand for them in 2024.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that the lens is not extending fully/evenly and is tilted.

The black thing in the corner is probably the lower auto lens cover blade not retracted fully because the lens isn't extended fully.

The battery dying while in use (turned on) had nothing to do with this.

You can inspect the lens barrel and hopefully see/remove some kind of obstruction it may have picked up in your bag. Otherwise, I would consider this unrepairable/uneconomical to repair.

Answer (score 1):

It's broken. It will almost certainly cost more to fix than another similar used camera. It's time to think about other options.

The only thing I might try if a fresh battery can be found fairly cheaply is to try a new battery that has been fully charged. Generic versions of the Panasonic DMW-BCF10E battery can be found on amazon in the U.S. for around $10.

Running some types of rechargeable batteries all the way down can damage them to the point they won't recharge to their original full capacity and there's an outside chance the lens isn't fully extending because the battery can't supply enough current to do it. But that's still a long shot.

If that doesn't work and you decide to find another similar used camera, that same battery fits a plethora of other Panasonic Lumix compact cameras from the same era:

DMC-FT4
DMC-TS1
DMC-TS2
DMC-TS3
DMC-TS4
DMC-FS10
DMC-FS11
DMC-FS12
DMC-FS15
DMC-FS25
DMC-FS30
DMC-FS33
DMC-FS4
DMC-FS42
DMC-FS6
DMC-FS62
DMC-FS7
DMC-FS8
DMC-FX25
DMC-FX40
DMC-FX48
DMC-FX60
DMC-FX65
DMC-FX66
DMC-FX68
DMC-FX70
DMC-FX75
DMC-FX550
DMC-FX580
DMC-FX700
DMC-F2
DMC-F3
DMC-FH1
DMC-FH20
DMC-FH22
DMC-FH3
DMC-FP8
DMC-FT1
DMC-FT2
DMC-FT3